# Using sed to delete lines - get 00 after each character

Tags: sed, files

I am trying to eliminate 3 first lines in every *.sql file for which I run the following command:

```
sed -i '1,3d' *.sql
```

It eliminates the lines with the side effect that after each character I get a symbol with 00 code (^a)

Why is this happening and how do I get rid of those symbols?

Here is a screenshot of what it becomes:

[image: screenshot of resulting file]

Comment: eliminate first 3 lines

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: try running `dos2unix *.sql` before the `sed` command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're editing a UTF16 file with an eight-bit aware utility.

Either convert the file using something like `iconv` or find a UTF16 aware utility to remove the first three lines of each file.

```
iconv --from-code=UTF16 --to-code=UTF8 < file16.txt > file8.txt
```

Comment: that was it, I actually regenerated the files in ascii and it worked as expected. Thanks!